# Azure Web App doesn't start node server

Tags: node.js, azure, typescript

I am publishing my typescript node.js/express azure app via bitbucket, and it appears that everything is compiling properly, however azure doesn't start the app.

A reproable repository is [here](https://bitbucket.org/somkun/azureexample). I tried cloning the app to a fresh local directory, then running the deploy.cmd and calling node start in the output folder, and that worked fine.

Comment: Your link to the repo does not work

Comment: fixed, error in formatting

Comment: @Somkun Fixed as in, you resolved your issue? If that's the case, you should delete this question.

Comment: Fixed the broken link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As node.js application on Azure Web Apps is not listening a classic number port, respond to web requests on the default port that iisnode listens.

you can try to modify your `main.ts` script:

```
let server: Server = new Server(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

And the requests against to node.js application on Azure Web Apps are handled via iisnode, you need to create a `web.config` configuration file in the root directory to config the entrance file, which is `bin\main.js` here in your scenario.

The `web.config` content example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
          <webSocket enabled="false" />
          <handlers>
               <!-- Indicates that the bin/main.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="bin/main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^bin/main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/main.js"/>
                    </rule>
               </rules>
          </rewrite>

          <!-- bin directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
          <security>
               <requestFiltering>
                    <hiddenSegments>
                         <remove segment="bin"/>
                    </hiddenSegments>
               </requestFiltering>
          </security>

          <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
          <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

          <!--
               You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
                 * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
                 * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
                 * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

               To debug your node.js application:
                 * set the debuggingEnabled option to "true"
                 * enable web sockets from the portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/garynodedeploy/configure
                 * browse to https://garynodedeploy.azurewebsites.net/bin/main.js/debug/

               See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
          -->
          <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js" debuggingEnabled="false" />
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode for more info about iisnode.

Comment: I was missing the port info. the web.config was not necessary, thanks!